# Работа с Microsoft Visual C++ Express 2010

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2010

Не могу разобраться, на один компьютер (Win7, 64 bit) установлена Microsoft Visual C++ Express 2010
Вот так выглядит обозреватель
[image]

На другой компьютер (Win7, 32 bit) также установлена Microsoft Visual C++ Express 2010
Обозреватель выглядит так
[image]

Программа, которая компилирует и работает на первом компе, на втором - вываливается куча ошибок  [image]

[image]

Почему такое происходит и что с этим делать?

Comment: может из за того, что в настройках проекта прописано компилировать 64битным компилятором? в случае 64 битной системы компилятор легко это делает. В случае 32 битной компилятор пытается компилировать как 32 битный код и несколько `ifdef` вырезают нужные определения.

Comment: А где можно поменять настройки проекта? попробую это сделать.

Comment: в настройках проекта.

Comment: stdafx.h и Stdafx.h это два разных файла… 

переименуйте Stdafx.h в stdafx.h

Comment: @подсолнух, а вод Windows не одно и то же?

Comment: @Construct не осведомлен в этом вопросе, но по ошибке же видно, что заголовочный файлы stdafx не найден… да и переименовать не так уж и сложно )

Comment: Может, пути в проекте прописаны абсолютные? На втором компе есть файл `D:\C++\Training\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\stdafx.h` ??